# When is this number irrational?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Lets say we have irrational numbers $\alpha _1, ..., \alpha _n$  in the interval $(0,1)$.  Represent each $\alpha _i$ as a binary expansion $0.a_i^1 a_i^2 ...$ where each $a_i^j \in \{0,1\}$.  Define the "dovetail" of the $\alpha _i$ to be the number with binary expansion $0.a_1^1a_2^1a_3^1...a_n^1 a_1^2 a_2^2 a_3^2...a_n^2 a_1^3a_2^3a_3^3...$.

I've been wondering: what are necessary and sufficient conditions on the $\alpha _i$ so that the dovetail is irrational?  My conjecture is that they should be linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ but I have no idea how to prove this. Also if you have any suggestions about how to tag or title this, please either let me know or feel free to add a tag yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's never rational. This follows from the fact that a real number is rational if and only if its binary expansion is eventually periodic (possibly with endless $0$s). Suppose the binary expansion of the dovetail has a recurring string of length $m$. Then it has a recurring string of length $mn$ (just take $n$ copies of the string of length $n$), and so each of the $\alpha_i$s has a periodic expansion.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Regardless of the base that you are working with, a decimal representation is periodic if and only if the number is rational.

If the dovetail is periodic with period $p$, show that $a_1$ must be periodic with period $pn$ (or possibly smaller).